# Scrapy Ignore Certificate Validation

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a site that has a certificate that can't be verified. I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname
```

The scraper used to work but I guess there has been a change on the server. I looked at the docs and found:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-clientcontextfactory

It states "Scrapy default context factory does NOT perform remote server certificate verification. This is usually fine for web scraping."

In my settings I don't have a context factory so the fact that it's verifying certificates is weird - or maybe I need to set a context factory?

In any case if someone can point me to a solution it would be appreciated.

Scrapy Version Info:

```
Scrapy    : 1.1.0
lxml      : 3.6.0.0
libxml2   : 2.9.4
Twisted   : 16.3.0
Python    : 2.7.10
pyOpenSSL : 0.13.1 (OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016)
Platform  : Darwin-16.0.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sh_scrapy/extension.py", line 65, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
for x in result:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/app/__main__.egg/meh/spiders/meh_spider.py", line 411, in parse_list
rloc = requests.get(location_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 65, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 599, in send
history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 192, in resolve_redirects
allow_redirects=False,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: hostname 'items.xaha.ca' doesn't match either of '*.xah.ca', 'xah.ca'
```

Comment: What version of scrapy are you using? (paste the output of `scrapy version -v` in your question). Latest [scrapy only issues warnings](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/tls.py) for certificate verification failures, not errors. Why is the question tagged `python-requests`? Are you mixing blocking python-requests and asynchronous scrapy code?

Comment: Also I tagged it with python-requests because I am using it for POST'ing Scrapy Items to an API. I guess I should be doing this in a pipeline but its working fine.

Comment: `ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname` is not what Scrapy outputs. Can you paste the whole traceback with this error? Also, can you try upgrading scrapy to at least 1.1.1? Also pyOpenSSL might be a bit old to have good TLS behavior

Comment: Okay, I updated the question with the full stack trace.

Comment: So this is a validation error from `python-requests`, not from `scrapy`. In `parse_list()`, you can use `rloc = requests.get(location_url, verify=False)`. Note that mixing blocking synchronous network calls using `python-requests` and aynchronous callback calls with scrapy, does not play well together usually.

Comment: I updated scrapy and now I get the following error: `2016-10-09 15:24:58 [scrapy] WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "items.xaha.ca"; VerificationError(errors=[DNSMismatch(mismatched_id=DNS_ID(hostname='items.xaha.ca'))])`

Comment: This is warning, not an error, and will not stop your spider. It's by design. Nothing to worry about